# How to apply all migrations to a new database?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, migration

I'm using ASP.NET Core v3.1. I have a `migration` folder as shown below. Now I've lost my database.

How can I apply all migrations to new database?

Running the command `update-database` doesn't work.

[image: et]

Comment: Running `update-database` would be the way to go - please elaborate the "doesn't work* - what exactly happens? Do you get an error - if so - **WHAT** error???

Comment: @marc_s is right but try context.Database.Migrate(); in your Startup.cs

Answer (score 1):

please make sure your database engine is available.
and next step make sure your context and your startup class and program class configured.